# mongodb validation jsonschema + expressive query failing to insert document

Tags: mongodb

So this is kind of a two part question. I have the follow validation schema defined:

```
db.createCollection(
  "users", {
    validator: {
      $or: [{
          company_name: {
            $exists: true,
            $type: "string"
          },
          type: {
            $in: [
              "creator"
            ],
            $exists: true,
            $type: "string"
          }
        },
        {
          firstname: {
            $exists: true,
            $type: "string",
          },
          lastname: {
            $exists: true,
            $type: "string",
          },
          type: {
            $in: [
              "user"
            ],
            $exists: true,
            $type: "string"
          }
        }
      ],
      $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        required: [
          "contacts",
          "created",
          "email",
          "password",
        ],
        properties: {
          "contacts": {
            bsonType: "array",
            items: {
              required: [
                "email",
                "name"
              ],
              properties: {
                "email": {
                  bsonType: "string",
                  description: "email of the other account"
                },
                "name": {
                  bsonType: "string",
                  description: "a way for the owner to easily identify"
                },
              }
            }
          },
          "created": {
            bsonType: "date",
            description: "the date this account was created"
          },
          "email": {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "owner's registered email"
          },
          "password": {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "a hashed password"
          },
          "reset_code": {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "part of the getter link to reset password"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

and I'm trying to insert:

```
db.users.insert({
    email: "sadf",
    password: "asdf",
    created: Date.now(),
    contacts: [],
    type: "user",
    firstname: "test",
    lastname: "test"
})
```

but it's giving me "Document failed validation"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be `created` with the `date` format. Instead of `Date.now()` I need to use `new Date()` or `new ISODate()`

Comment: Why not have a default on created with `Date.now` so you do not have to set it manually?

Comment: @Akrion I'm not sure what you mean. I thought MongoDB doesn't support defaults.

Comment: Sorry I though for some reason that you ware using mongoose.

Comment: @Akrion I was using it, but then I decided to move away from it, simply because I don't want more dependencies, and it forces me to understand mongoDB better without any crutches. And I hate how mongoose named their reserved words, which basically restricts your usable set of fields.

Comment: Yeah it has its advantages and disadvantages. But I hear you.